# Android GCMNetworkManager - Running a job between a specific timeframe everyday

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcm-network-manager, gcmtaskservice

I want to be able to run a periodic task within a certain timeframe every day, for example, between 8 AM and 11 AM. I'm not sure how I can do this with `PeriodicTask`, because you cannot specify a specific time of day.

I stumbled across [this example](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-can-i-run-a-job-at-a-specific-time-once-a-day), but it uses Evernote's Android-Job library. Is there a way to achieve this with `GCMNetworkManager` specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with GCMNetworkManager.

However, this level of time gating can be achieved with the [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview) as of the [February 2017 - v.10.2](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_v102) by [registering](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-register) a [`TimeFence`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/TimeFence) (more specifically, the [`inDailyInterval()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/TimeFence.html#inDailyInterval(java.util.TimeZone,%20long,%20long)) method).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Awareness API does not have APIs for connectivity (i.e., only when on Wifi).